# check permission of draw over apps for Custom ROM

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, custom-rom

As per standard android document we need to ask for permission on Marshmallow or newer versions. Right now I done with checking for M device and the particular permission. App is working fine on all devices.

**Actual Problem**

I come up with MIUI and similar Custom Android ROM. This ROM have introduce this feature on the 5.1.1 device. Here we had major breakdown.

If we check draw over apps on below Marshmallow its crashing on original ROM. Also we check for permission on MIUI device it not giving any result.

Tell me if you ever come How can app check/enable for draw over apps on the Custom ROM like MIUI?

Here is Code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if(!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getBaseContext())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
        Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_REQUEST_SETTING);
    } else{
        //Do Draw over apps
    }
} else {
    //Do Draw over apps
}
```

Comment: please share error log

Comment: Sorry no error logs. Its not starting chatheads.

Comment: I'm afraid you must ask user to enable it manually https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=9932

Comment: @DimaRostopira I Actually planning to make help screen for that. But there should be some better solution.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @NileshSingh Check added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Solved. MIUI updated their OS.